# Perl - Trouble With Loop Variables

Tags: perl

I'm fairly new to coding in Perl and am used to using C-style for loops.  I'm not sure why the following program never prints a value of 4 for $l:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $minL = 4;

for (my $l = $minL; $l > 0; $l--) {
    for (my $i = 0; $i + $l < $minL; $i++) {
        print "$i $l\n";
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your inner `for` loop has the condition `$i + $l < $minL`. If `$l == $minL`, then `$i + $l < $minL` will be false even if `$i` is 0, so the loop runs 0 times and never prints anything.

Maybe you wanted to use `<=` for the condition?

By the way, here is how you could write the same thing (assuming the `<=` condition) using Perl-style foreach loops:

```
my $minL = 4;
for my $l (reverse 1 .. $minL) {
    for my $i (0 .. $minL - $l) {
        print "$i $l\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first iteration:

```
for (my $l = $minL; $l > 0; $l--) {
```

$l == $minL

```
    for (my $i = 0; $i + $l < $minL; $i++) {
```

So this block won't run until $l is decremented:

```
        print "$i $l\n";
    }
```

Change your inner loop to:

```
    for (my $i = 0; $i + $l <= $minL; $i++) {
```